# How to open URL in Android before the main activity starts?

Tags: android, android-activity

In Android Main activity, how can I call URL without button ?

Example : When the application opened, the URL will open without browser and main activity will be null.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to open an URL before the main activity is started?

Comment: use webview. search google writing webview in android

Comment: I want to send info using GET method with this link before the main activity started. @CorneliuDascălu

Comment: You can't do something before an Activity starts.  You can do it when it starts.  Or you can put up a loading screen, get it while the loading screen is up, and launch your real activity when its done loading.

Comment: GET requests are usually used to retrieve info, not to send, but anyway, maybe you don't have a choice. You have to be aware that you have no guarantee that the request will complete before the activity is started.

Comment: Easy to say. How can I do it ? @GabeSechan

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to launch a server request before the main activity is even created. To do that, you first have to subclass the Application class, then its `onCreate()` you can start a new thread and launch your server request.

Like I mentioned in a comment, there is no guarantee that the request will complete before the main activity starts. In fact, it's almost guaranteed that the activity will start before the request even reaches the server.

Also, I recommend using a library like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for server requests.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for your help.